# Sort values of a Map in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I have a map where a key holds multiple values

```
datamap = [ 'Antenna Software':[ 'Salarpuria', 'Cessna', 'Vrindavan Tech', 'Alpha Center' ],
             'Ellucian':[ 'Malvern', 'Ellucian House', 'Residency Road'] ]
```

here i need to  alphabetically sort the values

```
datamap = [ 'Antenna Software':[ 'Alpha Center', 'Cessna', 'Salarpuria', 'Vrindavan Tech' ],
            'Ellucian':[ 'Ellucian House', 'Malvern', 'Residency Road' ] ]
```

how to do it in groovy way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
def sortedMap = datamap.sort().collectEntries { k, v ->
  [ k, v.sort( false ) ]
}
```

If you're not bothered about sorting the keys of the map, you can get rid of the initial `sort()`:

```
def sortedMap = datamap.collectEntries { k, v ->
  [ k, v.sort( false ) ]
}
```

#### Explanation of `sort( false )`:

[By default, the `sort` method in Groovy changes the original list](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#sort%28%29), so:

```
// Given a List
def a = [ 3, 1, 2 ]

// We can sort it
def b = a.sort()

// And the result is sorted
assert b == [ 1, 2, 3 ]

// BUT the original list has changed too!
assert a != [ 3, 1, 2 ] && a == [ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

So [if you pass `false` to `sort`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#sort%28boolean%29), it leaves the original list alone, and just returns the sorted list:

```
// Given a List
def a = [ 3, 1, 2 ]

// We can sort it (passing false)
def b = a.sort( false )

// And the result is sorted
assert b == [ 1, 2, 3 ]

// AND the original list has remained the same
assert a == [ 3, 1, 2 ]
```

Comment: Why it is v.sort( false ) ??  what that "false " says?

Comment: def dataMap = [:]
  Client.list(sort: "name", order: "desc").each { client ->
   dataMap[client] = client.venues
  }
  
  def sortedMap = dataMap.collectEntries { k, v ->
    [ k, v.sort( false ) ]
  }
this fails

Comment: Fails in what way?  Just saying _"this fails"_ doesn't help much...  Try: `def sortedMap = Client.list( sort:'name', order:'desc' ).collectEntries { client -> [ client.name, client.venues.name.sort() ] }` (assuming venue has a `name` property)

Comment: Client has a list of venues client.venues.name.sort() does not work

Comment: @monda  _"does not work"_ is no better than _"this fails"_ please update your question with your actual problem and any error messages you get